# How to store & retrieve NSArray object in sqlite database in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I want to store & retrieve NSArray object in single column of sqlite database.
Does anyone knows how i can achieve that?

Comment: can you show some example

Comment: grade : [
{
  "gradeId" : 123,
  "gradeName" : "abc"
},
{
   "gradeId" : 222,
    "gradeName" : "xyz"
}
]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is convert the array to JSON string and store the string in database and while fetching the data convert the JSON string to array again.

Array to JSON

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arrayObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil]
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

JSON to Array

```
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *arrayObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
```

Comment: https://github.com/jmbarnardgh/labqlite and https://github.com/jmbarnardgh/labqlite_model_generator may be able to assist you with the SQLite part

Comment: i am also using the library https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb and https://github.com/nerdyc/FMDBHelpers to interact with the SQLite database file and i have a class which contains functions for CRUD operation for required models. Those are also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's many way to do this. One of the simple is use **componentsJoinedByString** method.

```
NSArray* someArray = @[.....];
NSString* result = [someArray componentsJoinedByString:@"<some separator>"];
```

Also you can **NSKeyedArchiver**

```
NSArray* someArray = @[.....];
NSData* dataToSave = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:someArray];
```

But you will provide object in array that confirm to the **NSCoding** protocol.

Also you can use json serialisation:

```
NSArray* someArray = @[.....];
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:someArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil]
```